# Non-linear PDE with steady state solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

What are some popular choices for a non-linear PDE with a well-defined steady state solution? I am looking for canonical problems in one or two dimensions with easily verifiable results to test my methodology.

Comment: What do you mean a well-defined steady state solution?

Comment: I meant well known or well understood. I am trying to pick a test problem to serve as a benchmark case.